# TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable eventhough using another variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

First post ever :)
I know that the if statement returns a Boolean value. But I am not using it to iterate a list, I'm using x. I just want all other variables (type = IntVar) to be set to 0 except for i which has to remain 1. Thanks in advance, my first ever time here...

```
def clear():
    variables=[var, var0, var1, var2, var3, var4,var5,var6, var7, var8]
    for i in variables:
        if i.get() == 1:
            x = variables.index(i)
            for y in variables in range(0,x-1) and range(x,9):
                y.set(0)
```

My original code is 500 lines long so not ideal to post it full here.
Full traceback:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Thomas Jence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "G:\Mrs. Odewale\Computing coursework\options.py", line 187, in clear9
    for y in variables in range(0,x-1) and range(x,9):
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

Comment: you have to format your code. no one can read what you wrote.

Comment: Sorry just learnt how to do that now.. My bad...

Comment: not sure what language this is, but are var, var0, var1 all undefined? if so, I wouldn't expect you to do a i.get() on them.

Comment: Basically var is the variable for a checkbutton in my python tkinter program which will be 1 if checked and 0 if left blank. I have tried i.get() and it works, so does the index but when I do the second for loop, it comes up with that error. I have many checkbuttons, hence many vars. Sorry im just learning how to use stackoverflow, thanks for being patient

Comment: most likely your problem is that you are re-writing the values of the array while you are looping through them, which is never a good idea.

Comment: Any advice on solving that issue if it might be that?

Comment: We don't need to see all your code. Instead, you need to create a [mcve] that reproduces this problem.

Comment: Your issue comes from this line `for y in variables in range(0,x-1) and range(x,9):`. What is that?

Answer (score 1):

```
for y in variables in range(0,x-1) and range(x,9):
```

is interpreted as (split up with parentheses and by line to make groupings clear):

```
for y in (
          variables in (
                        range(0, x-1) and range(x,9)
                                                    )
                                                     ):
```

The innermost parentheses then determine if `range(0, x-1)` is empty or not, and use it if it's not, and use `range(x,9)` if it is. The next layer then tests if `variables` is in the "winning" `range`. Then you effectively do:

```
for y in False:
```

because `variables` is a `list`, so it's definitely not in any `range`.

I don't know what you're trying to do, but you need to reconsider that line.

Answer (score -3):

Not familiar with python, but as a standard coding practice you never want to change values in an array while you are iterating through them.

Instead create a new array, which has same values as the existing array. iterate the old array while setting values of the new array, and then after the loop, set the your array to the new values of the new array.